# what is wrong with this simple js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code not show the div with the id of blink?

I think I have done every thing right, when I click the button it should display the div.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="display:none; id="blink"">
    <p>we do not supppport your browser</p>
</div>

<script>
    var isChrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome"));
    if (isChrome) 
    {
        $('#blink').show();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Typo: isChroem (isChrome)

Comment: You mixed the `id` and `style` attribute.

Comment: Look at your console, there's so many typo's here.

Comment: The value returned by `indexOf` will be `-1` if the string `"Chrome"` can't be found, and it's a "true" value. And if the sub-string if first then the returned value will be `0` which is "false", meaning your logic is flawed.

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. The example code is too general - you're testing isChrome and showing elements together. Try checking them seperately before you post a question.

Comment: Please do not down vote the question. I am new to the site and will learn and try to ask a more through question next time. The information provided so far has helped me so much, i would like to come back to this if i get stuck.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the typos, the code won't work as you think it does because `String.indexOf(substring)` returns, on success, the position of the start of the substring in the containing string (which could be `0`), and, on failure, returns `-1`.

Try:

```
var isChrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1);
```

... however, please be careful with UA-sniffing. If you're just alerting users to your support, fair enough, but don't be lured into turning site features off and on based on browser and not at least a feature detection library is going to cause you maintainability problems and infuriate your users.

Comment: And what does it do on other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

A syntax error is causing it to not show. You have an issue with the talking marks. Change your div html to:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="blink">
    <p>we do not supppport your browser</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, realised it after I posted it. Fixed

Comment: Still not working, get this error file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2014-12-28 21:07:08.855index.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: That is so strange, i have been using jquery from the google ddn for so long and this is the first time it has not worked.

Comment: you're trying to run the html file directly from your file system instead of through a web server. so it's trying to load the jquery source from your filesystem.

Comment: @codeforfun The problem is, that you load your HTML from the `file::` protocol. Either add `http/s` to the url or load your HTML file from a server via `http/s`

Answer (score 1):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1/jquery.min.js is not valid.

But you can use this one instead (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js)

So...:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Code</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div style="display:none;" id="blink">
    <p>we do not support your browser</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     // Edit : index checking as user52889 said :)
      var isChrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1 );
      if (isChrome) {
        $('#blink').show();
      };

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some typo. As second, more elegant way to check browser in use is: `!!window.chrome`

Take a look at my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/f4qdtqgs/5/

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;

if (isChrome) {
    $("#blink").show();
};
```